# What are available KPRIORITIES?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, kernel

[Set Priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553265(v=vs.85).aspx)
What are all possible priorities in KPRIORITY in win kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for KeQueryPriorityThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553062(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Thread priorities range from 0 to 31, where 0 is the lowest priority and 31 is the highest.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all valued defined in winddk.h.
This is the excerpt for you

```
#define LOW_PRIORITY                      0
#define LOW_REALTIME_PRIORITY             16
#define HIGH_PRIORITY                     31
#define MAXIMUM_PRIORITY                  32
```